# How to get the best current location with a time limited search?

Tags: android, timer, gps, runnable, currentlocation

I want to know a way to search for current location limited by a timer.
During that timer, the app should search various possibilities for current location which they will be filtered to get the best estimation. 
Basically, I'm trying to do this:

> 1. Enable GPS providers;
> 2. Inside a runnable code, request updates to location from them, and then execute some way to filtered and obtain the best estimation;
> 3. The runnable should execute during a predefined timer or if the user cancel the search, it should stop.

Anyone have any idea to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is globle variable

```
Location loc;
double latitude;
double longitude;
LocationManager mLocationManager;
```

this is bind location manager

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            100, 3, mLocationListener);
```

this class

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        // your code here
        latitude = location.getLatitude();//set here your current location latitude & longitude.
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.e(KEY_TAG, "Lat " + latitude + "Long " + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

when user location is change that a time to you will get the new lat long.

Comment: I'm already been doing that @Hardik Parmar, tks anyway. My main problem is about how to doing a runnable executing only during a timer.